# I can't seem to get a Docker-Nginx-Django app to refresh the static files

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I currently have a Django website that runs on a server using Nginx an Docker. Every time I update my main css file and deploy it, nothing changes, despite hard refreshing the site. When new static files are added, they end up working, but modified files don't seem to change.

This led me to believing that nginx or Docker was caching the file.

I've tried the following:
Clearing the cache in the nginx container, setting the lines `expires -1` and `sendfile off`, rebuilding the containers, with no luck.

The last time I had this problem, I believe I had to delete the volume for it to refresh, which I don't think is a good solution.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

**Settings:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

**nginx configuration**:

```
upstream my_server {
    server web:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $Host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /code/staticfiles/;
        expires -1;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;
    
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /code/staticfiles/;
        expires -1;
    }

}
```

**Docker Compose File**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
        environment:
            - ENVIRONMENT=production
            - SECRET_KEY=@^la7#2kl%8$$o9rl)8$$aqvrwq5_x1=r!xc-1p#+(!m4r2vue*&
            - DEBUG=0
            - EMAIL_HOST_USER=apikey
            - EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=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
        volumes:
            - .:/code
            - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
        networks:
            - nginx_network
            - db_network
        depends_on:
            - db
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.17.0
        ports: 
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
            - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
        depends_on: 
            - web
        networks:
            - nginx_network
        command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s
        reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    db:
        image: postgres:11
        env_file:
            - config/db/db_env
        networks:
            - db_network
        volumes:
            - db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    certbot:
        image: certbot/certbot
        volumes:
            - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
        entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew;
        sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
networks:
    nginx_network:
        driver: bridge
    db_network:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    db_volume:
    static_volume:
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7


# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code


# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system



# Copy project
COPY . /code/



RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y cron


CMD /code/script_prod.sh
```

Comment: You have to collectstatic

Comment: Yes, I have done so already. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be the problem :(